# How to star ground in a breadboard?

Tags: grounding, breadboard

How would one go about star grounding on a breadboaard? As I understand star grounding means connecting all wires to one point ground. How could you put all the wires into onee hole on the breadboard, they would not fit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wouldn't be connecting all the wires to one hole. You'd twist their ends together, use solder to secure the connection, and then have one extra wire in the bunch go to the GND rail from the supply.

An alternative that works well is a ground plane: stick a thin piece of copper, bronze or even stainless sheet on the bottom of the breadboard, have it stick out 0.5" or so all around the perimeter, and solder ground wires to it on said perimeter.

[image]

Comment: But in this second example arent there multiple ground points again since they are all connected to multiple points on  a metal sheet?

Comment: Oooh, I should do that, jumper wires to a copper plane, nice. @LEXORAI : a metal sheet is as good of a single-point connection as you'll get on a breadboard.  If you're using a breadboard, you must not be very picky about the tiny voltage drops that would suggest a star-grounding approach.  There are also many good reasons NOT to use a star-grounding approach, at least not the naive implementation of them often seen in audio circles for instance.

Comment: @TimWilliams I've used this for decades with quite reasonable results. Anything with high gain will really appreciate having a ground plane. Even a "simple" microphone, ultrasonic transducer, or photodiode amplifier on a breadboard is "noise receiver" without. At DC, that sheet is much lower impedance than any typical ground plane inside a 4-layer commodity PCB - it's an order of magnitude thicker at least. And you can always use a thicker sheet if you got a good enough soldering iron :)

Comment: *But in this second example arent there multiple ground points again since they are all connected to multiple points on a metal sheet?* 0.15mm of copper is 0.1milli-ohm/square at room temp. That's about the thickness of the sheet I used in the picture. The resistance between the opposite corners of the sheet (along the diagonal) is usually *dominated by the resistance of solder joints and connecting wires*, and is on the order of 1mOhm into solder, more along the wire. The sheet metal is just about an ideal conductor in that scenario, and is quite close to the ideal of a single-point ground.

Comment: I have a mic circuit with an amplifier. I have noise at the output probably because not grounding correctly. So you are saying using one of the methods for example the second one would work on such a circuit? What is the difference between simply connecting multiple points on one rail on a breadboard and connecting it to a sheet of metal. Are they not both copper?

Comment: Try passing 10A through connections on the breadboard :) Many breadboards will overheat. That piece of sheet metal will do nothing, it won't even notice it. There are two things here: **very low** DC and audio frequency impedance between all the points, *and* the shielding effect of a ground plane. Breadboards are **notorious** for how much noise they pick up without a ground plane. I consider them next to useless without a ground plane you can solder stuff to as needed. Basically, that sheet  is pretty much an ideal DC single node, no matter where you solder a wire to it - in breadboard use.

Comment: But I still do not seem to understand why would then connecting two points on a rail be different than connecting on a metal sheet? What noise does a rail on a breadboard pick up that a metal sheet does not?

Comment: For best shielding effect it's important to have about 1-2" of the ground plane sticking out - the example I show is a not the best in that respect. That's because the circuitry is elevated above the plane, and the more elevated it is, the farther the shield has to extend laterally.

Comment: @LEXORAI Noise *voltage* is measured between any two points. The lower the impedance between those points, the lower the noise voltage, everything else being equal. When the impedance is low enough, there is no measurable voltage difference between the 0V nodes in the circuit, and that node acts more or less like the abstract node in circuit analysis. The impedance of the breadboard contacts and rail material is order of magnitude higher than the impedance of connections made by soldering to even a 0.05mm thick piece of sheet metal, although 0.1mm or thicker is preferred.

Comment: Ok so essentially it is because soldering makes a better connecton than simply putting a wire in a hole on a breadboard?

Comment: If you want to try it - and I suggest you do - get sheets at least 0.1mm thick, and have them extend about 5cm outside of the breadboard, like if you had a 5cm margin between the sheet edge and the breadboard edge. Connect *short* ground wires from each "0V" point in the circuit to the nearest point on the sheet and solder them down. It'll be about the best you can get on a breadboard in terms of ground integrity. There is nothing else you can do besides adding a shielding cover over the entire breadboard.

Comment: @LEXORAI And also because the impedance of a large piece of sheet metal is lower than impedance of narrow cheap strips of who knows what used in manufacture of affordable breadboards. For professional use I only ever used 3M solderless breadboards, but those are expensive. You get what you pay for. And they still need a ground plane.

Comment: Ok I understand now. The only thing left is to find out where to get a metal sheet of such dimensions lol

Comment: Though I also like the first method seems more easily doable since I do not have a metal sheet

Comment: @LEXORAI: copper sheets and copper clad boards available at Amazon.

Comment: Copper sheet! Great idea: wish I had thought of it years ago.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Nice ground plane

Comment: Can the sheet be out of aluminum?